# Laravel counting database rows with same name field

Tags: laravel

imagine a table like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sam |
| 2 | lily |
| 3 | sam |
| 4 | tom |
| 5 | lily |

i want to count the number of times that each name is repeated and store it in a variable.

expected result :count sam = 2 ,count lily = 2, count tom = 1

how can i do such thing in laravel?

Comment: Do you know how to do it without Laravel i.e. with an SQL query?

Comment: These basic "how to" questions are generally not received positively unless you show us an honest attempt to solve the problem yourself instead of wording it in an almost demanding way

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function totalRepeatedName() {
    $total = User::groupBy('name')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as count, name')
    ->pluck('count', 'name');
    return $total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your model name is 'User'

```
$usernames = [];
$usercounts = [];

$names = User::->groupby('name')->get();

foreach ($names as $key => $name) {

$data = User::where('name', $name->name)->count();

array_push($usernames, $name->name);
array_push($usercounts, $data);
}
```

values will be available in $usernames and $usercounts. if you want them in same array use key value pair array